# NodeJs localhost:5000 cannot assces

Tags: node.js

[npm run dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hijTT.png)

[Unable to access localhost. It spins forever :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgGuI.png)

[Mycode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y09X.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use cookieParser like this. You can refer docs [here](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html)

```
app.use(cookieParser())
```

Comment: I'm really sorry that I just uploaded pictures.
It worked
Thank you so much <3

Comment: Please try to put code, that is the reason your question is getting downvoted